# How to justify some independent research experience for graduate admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions

If somebody has some research experience but no publication could come out of it, then how to justify that experience except the recommendation by the supervisor in front of the graduate admission committee? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Say a bit more in your question about the situation. Is this undergraduate research or totally independent of any school? Or is it something else entirely? What field are you working in. Possibly even the country would help people answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE Academia. I think your question would benefit from adding further details, to ensure you get the best possible feedback.

Comment: I have done some work on machine vision as an intern for an organization. I worked for two months there. Now, though the work was good (as told by the supervisor) but a publication couldn't come out of it. Also, I don't want to add any recommendation letter from that supervisor while applying to a grad school.    However, I want to include that work into SOP and CV. How to justify my work that I have done there?